# Updating Panel with new values in GAS UI

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I have a huge spreadsheet matrix, from which I create a long list of check boxes. The users then select different abilities, press search. The code the cross-checks with the database spreadsheet, returning names of the persons who has those abilities.

I need to update the "rightPanel" with the results of my search. But i simple can't figure out how to - if at all posible - update a panel in my UI..

```
var dataSSkey = 'sheetID'; //datasheet ID
var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dataSSkey).getSheetByName('Ansatte');
var groupsArray = [[],[],[],[]]; 
var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
var dataArray  = dataSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastColumn).getValues();
var numberGroups
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Find Consultant');
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
var leftPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setWidth(450);
var rightPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setWidth(450);
var grid = app.createGrid(1, 2).setId('myGrid')

var outputArray = []; //to store output from search

var positiveList = [[],[]]; //array to store name and folder-ID of consultants matching
var numberPositive = 0; //number of consultants matching

function doGet() {
  buildGroupsArray()

  addCheckBoxesToUI()

  var scrollPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setHeight(460);

  //Search button
  var searchButton = app.createButton('Search'); 
  var clickHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("respondToSearch");
  searchButton.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
  clickHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);

  var spacerImage = app.createImage("http://www.bi..ge.jpg").setHeight(3);

  scrollPanel.add(panel);
  rightPanel.add(app.createLabel('resultat her'));


  leftPanel.add(scrollPanel);
  leftPanel.add(spacerImage);
  leftPanel.add(searchButton);

  grid.setWidget(0, 0, leftPanel)
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, rightPanel);

  app.add(grid);

  return app;
}
function respondToSearch(e){
var numberLogged = 0;

//define firstEmpty
var firstEmpty = "A"+lastRow;
if(lastRow !== 1){
  firstEmpty = "A"+(lastRow+1);
};

//find selected competencies --> store in array + count competencies 
for(i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++){
if (e.parameter["Checkbox"+i] == "true") {
  var value = e.parameter["CheckboxValue"+i];
  outputArray[numberLogged] = value;
  numberLogged++;
  }
}

for(i = 2; i <= lastColumn; i++){
   var numberCorrect = 0;

//Run through rows according to content of output from selection
for(j in outputArray){

   //Check if consultant own selected competency
   if(dataArray[outputArray[j]][i] == "x"){
     numberCorrect++; //if consultant owns selected competency then count
     }
   }

  //if consultant owns all competencies, then add name and folder-id to array
  if(numberCorrect == numberLogged){
    positiveList[0][numberPositive] = dataArray[1][i]; //Add consultant name
    positiveList[1][numberPositive] = dataArray[2][i]; //Add consultant-folder ID
    numberPositive++ //count the number of consultants that own all competencies
    }
  }

for(j in positiveList[0]){
   var name = positiveList[0][j];
   var id = positiveList[1][j];
   Logger.log(name);
   Logger.log(id)
   var anchor = app.createAnchor(name,'https://ww......folderviewid='+id);
rightPanel.add(anchor)
}
return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the problem you have...

In your handler function you only have to use `app=UiApp.getActiveApplication()` and from there populate the panel exactly the same way you did it in the `doGet()` function, ending with a `return app;` that will actually update the current Ui.

There are dozens of examples all around... did I misunderstand something in your question ?

---

**Edit :**  following your comment.

I suppose you defined your variables outside of the doGet function hoping they will become global and so available to all the functions in your script but this is not going to work. Global variables in Google Apps script can't be updated by functions.
I would strongly recommend that you create app and panels in the doGet function and give them an ID so that you can get them back and update their values (or content) from the handler functions.

Here is a re-written version of your code (didn't test)
: (some parts are not reproduced (see //...)

```
var dataSSkey = 'sheetID'; //datasheet ID
var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dataSSkey).getSheetByName('Ansatte');
var groupsArray = [[],[],[],[]]; 
var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
var dataArray  = dataSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastColumn).getValues();
var numberGroups

var outputArray = []; //to store output from search

var positiveList = [[],[]]; //array to store name and folder-ID of consultants matching
var numberPositive = 0; //number of consultants matching

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Find Consultant');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var leftPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setWidth(450).setId('leftPanel');
  var rightPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setWidth(450).setId('rightPanel');;
  var grid = app.createGrid(1, 2).setId('myGrid')
  buildGroupsArray(app); // in this function get app as parameter or use UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  addCheckBoxesToUI(app);// in this function get app as parameter or use UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var scrollPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setHeight(460);
//...
//...  
  return app;
}
function respondToSearch(e){
//...
//...
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var rightPanel = app.getElementById('rightPanel');

  for(j in positiveList[0]){
    var name = positiveList[0][j];
    var id = positiveList[1][j];
    Logger.log(name);
    Logger.log(id)
    var anchor = app.createAnchor(name,'https://ww......folderviewid='+id);
    rightPanel.add(anchor)
  }
  return app;
}
```

Comment: I use this piece of code to populate the panel in my "respondToSearch"   `for(j in positiveList[0]){
    var name = positiveList[0][j];
    var id = positiveList[1][j];
    Logger.log(name);
    Logger.log(id)
    var anchor = app.createAnchor(name,'https://drive.google.com/.../folderview?id='+id);
    rightPanel.add(anchor)
    //resultPanel.add(anchor)
  }` but it dosn't update my panel.

Comment: Where do you define rightPanel?  And don't forget the return app; I'll edit my answer with more details.

Comment: it's defined as a "global" varible at the very top of my code. `return app;`is there.

Comment: I had put var rightPanel = app.getElementById('rightPanel'); in the loop, bad idea, sorry. code updated.